# GWT RequestFactory and GWT Designer compatibility issue

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwt-designer

I recently upgraded my project from GWT RPC to GWT RequestFactory, my UI uses alot DTO classes that was pure java classes, but now I upgrade them to entityproxy.

Now gwt designer is complaining that the entity class(JPA Entity) present in locator is illegal.I also use Gucie in locator to inject service implementation.

How could I fix this.

thx.

Comment: Please provide little more details like whats there in your JPA entity etc. I have not used designer, but have used GWT and bit of RF. So I will try to help. Thanks

Comment: Your EntityProxy classes should be separate from your JPA classes.  To use injection in your locator classes you need some special wiring (search for injected-request-factory).  But to help you we need some more info.  Post some code and tell us how you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Like LPD said, provide more details. Some details are important to understand why it doesn't work.

"Java doesn't work, please help" -> you know the feeling.

For a given entity, you could post the entity class itself, the related proxy, parts of the service methods and annotations, as well as your relevant parts of your locator and request context class.

Go through this check list:

1. Check your annotations (*ProxyFor*, etc.)
2. Check your *RequestContext* and its annotations
3. Check your services definition.
4. Ensure that your service, locator definitions are in sync with what is specified in the *RequestContext*.